# Flutter - Android app localized app name showing inside of app in dark bar

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am working on an app where I have to set localized app name in English and Arabic. So, I have followed all the requirements and it worked fine. So, now when I set language to Arabic, app label automatically sets to Arabic and in English it sets to English.

**Here are my files:**

Folder & file structure ->
[image]

*values/strings.xml ->*

`<resources> <string name="appName">OneWordAddress</string> </resources>`

*values-ar/strings.xml ->*

`<resources> <string name="appName">عنوانك بكلمة</string> </resources>`

*src/main/AndroidManifest.xml ->*

[AndroidManifest.xml](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/yCJ2k9t7wq/)

But the problem is, the app name is showing inside of app in dark bar at the top of app. The app starts after the dark bar. So, if device locale in English it shows English app label in dark bar and if locale is Arabic then in dark bar it shows Arabic app name.

[image]

I didn't add anything in top of appbar. So, there is no chance of showing this dark bar from Flutter code.

Answer (score 3):

Just goto your AndroidManifest.xml class and under the MainActivity added, change the theme to NoTitleBar

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```